# How to change wordpress category list url

Tags: permalinks

Hi i want to change this url adress :

https://www.websitename.com/cat/scottish-fold/page/2/

To :

https://www.websitename.com/cat/scottish-fold?page=2

How to do that 
I want to do this because for seo.

For Example:
https://www.searchenginejournal.com/seo-friendly-pagination/275557/